# Is evaporative cooling more efficient with dry or moist air?

Tags: thermodynamics, water, air

I live in India, and in the summer season, the temperature can reach up to $45 \sideset{^\circ}{}{\mathrm{C}} .$ We use Split 1.5 Ton AC in our small office. The idea is to put an evaporative cooler on the inlet side of the heat exchanger of AC to give it more efficient cooling.

Will it help to increase efficiency? or COP? By how much?

Comment: The [Evaporative cooler wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaporative_cooler) has the following sentence in the introduction: *For example, an evaporative cooler may be designed to cool the coils of a large air conditioning or refrigeration system to increase its efficiency.*

Comment: It depends what you're trying to cool. Evaporating water into the dry output of an air conditioner will reduce the absolute temperature, which is good for cooling machines. But the reduced evaporation of sweat will cancel the effect for humans, and the added humidity may have negative side-effects like mildew.

Comment: Sure.  It is thus a two-stage.  If you have questions on the details of efficiency or design, you might modify this question, or ask another.  In my time here, I haven't found a string community for handling the details of HVAC systems, but focused areas of the HVAC process might get hook those with enough experience in the physical sciences.

Comment: iamgopal, read the wiki page that BMS linked you to.  Also, if possible, you don't want to increase the humidity of the air entering the air conditioner, and the wiki page gives details about how to do that.

Comment: What’s the typical relative humidity of outside air?

Comment: What does COP stand for?

Comment: @dllahr Coefficient of Performance

Answer (score 1):

If you’re recirculating the office-side air, evaporative cooling is unlikely to help.  You’d be adding water vapor to the air which the AC would eventually just have to use cooling power to remove.

Depending on humidity, though, it may be very effective to use evaporative cooling to reduce the temperature of the air reaching the outside (hot side) coils. That’s once-through air flow.

Answer (score -1):

I think it will increase efficiency,
Compared to a normal AC there will be a significant change.
I dont know the exact change.
But you will probably feel a difference.

Answer (score -1):

This is what i have seen work well in my home town.  If your climate us dry evaporator cooler will help. 1st make syre your condensing unit outside gas some shade cover then blow the evaporated air onto to the condensing unit outside.  If you blow tge evaporated air inside it will raise the humidity inside your office, and humid air is more difficult to cool (takes more energy to cool )